# Django actions on admin re-query SQL so time waiting is double

Tags: python, django

I have model using the DjangoQLSearchMixin for filtering

```
class FollowerAdmin(DjangoQLSearchMixin, NumericFilterModelAdmin, SpecialActions):
```

and I use also

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
```

I get the results on the admin page, later I export to csv using :

[image]

But it do the sql query over again after I export.
Any idea Y ?